# Prove that $E[e^{2(m−1)X^2}]\le m$

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value, probability-inequalities

I'm reading "[Understanding Machine Learning: From theory to algorithms](https://www.cse.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf)".

### The problem is as follows, which is Exercise 31.1 of the book on page 416.

Let $X$ be a random variable that satisﬁes

$P[X \ge\epsilon]\le e^{−2m\epsilon^2}$ .

Prove that $E[e^{2(m−1)X^2}]\le m$.

Comment: What is your question, are you looking for hints? Have you made any attempts at solving the exercise? What is it specifically that you are not able to do or understand about the exercise?

Comment: I have no clue at all.

Comment: Read about LOTUS, the _[Law Of The Unconscious Stastician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)_ and apply to find an expression for $E[e^{2(m-1)X^2}]$ in terms of the distribution of $X$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate You do not have any information about the distribution of $X$ other than that $P(X \geq \epsilon) \leq e^{-2m\epsilon^2}.$

Answer (score 2):

This one involves a series of tricks. I was able to solve it in the following way. First, use the given assumption to bound $\mathbb{E}(X^{2k})$, by writing $\mathbb{E}(X^{2k}) = \int_{0}^{\infty}P(X^{2k} \geq t)$. Then, rewrite $e^{2(m-1)x^2}$ by plugging $2(m-1)x^2$ into the Taylor expansion of $e^x.$ Subsequently, apply the monotone convergence theorem to see that you can take the expectation of each term of the series. If you do all these computations correctly you get that the integral of the series is bounded by the geometric series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^k = m.$